# Как обработать новое сообщение в чате?

Tags: delphi, webbrowser

Делаю помощника для чата на сайте (чат - бот, если угодно), и столкнулся с проблемой проверки ключевого слова (команды "!help"). Осуществляю проверку в таймере. Написал примитивный вариант с поиском ключевого слова в исходнике записанном в `StringList`:

```
find:='!help';
  SrcCode.Clear;
  SrcCode.Add(GetHtml(WB_Doc));
  for i:=0 to SrcCode.Count - 1 do
  if pos(find, SrcCode.Strings[i]) > 0 then begin
    Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово найдено';
    SpeedButton2.Click;
  end else Label1.Caption:='Ничего';
```

Работает, но как и следовало ожидать, с интервалом в каждые 3 секунды я получаю сообщение о том что ключевое слово найдено и выполняется ответ на запрос в чат.

Решил копать в сторону поиска ключевого слова в элементах страницы:

```
  DocChat: IHTMLElementCollection;
  chatElement: IHTMLElement;

  DocChat:=(webbrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).all.tags('span') as IHTMLElementCollection;
  for i:=0 to DocChat.Length-1 do
  begin
    chatElement:=DocChat.item(i,0)as IHTMLElement;
    if (chatElement.className='message') and (chatElement.innerText='!help') then begin
      Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово найдено';
      SpeedButton2.Click;
    end else Label1.Caption:='Ничего';
  end;
```

Но успехов в этом деле не было. Не ищется. Если бы в этом случае поиск и производился, то все равно эффект был бы тем же самым (каждые 3 секунды "Ключевое слово найдено").

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать поиск команды "!help" в таймере, без проблемы с зацикливанием. Т.е. как появляется новое сообщение с ключевым словом - выполнить один раз:

```
  Label1.Caption:='Ключевое слово найдено';
  SpeedButton2.Click;
```

если снова получено ключевое слово, ещё раз выполнить те же самые команды.

P.S. На "html" странице в чате имеется `div` с классом `chat-line`, в нем `span` с классом `timestamp`, в который записывается время опубликованного комментария (12:45) и ещё один `span`, с классом `message`, в котором содержится сам комментарий.
Я думаю это можно как - то использовать, но комментарии с командой могут отправляться несколько раз в минуту, поэтому вряд ли эта информация чем то поможет.

**UPD:** Насчет порядкового номера, я не совсем представляю как должен выглядеть код присваивания найденному ключевому слову порядкового номера и реагирование не более 1 раза. Стоит учитывать что через n-ное количество комментариев в чате более старые сообщения пропадают из исходного кода.

**UPD:** Помогите пожалуйста, я честно не знаю как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Вам нужно как-то запоминать найденное слово и не реагировать на него больше 1 раза. Например смотреть метки времени у сообщений, или порядковый номер или число сообщений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант не идеален, но можно попробовать как вариант.

- Создать обработчик сообщений, который будет через какой то промежуток времени или по событию обновлять массив в котором будет хранится hash строки (сообщение + время + еще нужная информация. Чем уникальнее строка тем лучше) и счетчик в который записывается количество упоминаний ключевого слова `!help`. При следующей проверке не найденные записи удаляются, новые добавляются.
- Следующее сканирование находит все ключевые слова, генерирует для сообщения hash строки и проверяет к-во с первого шага, если количество больше - значит мы получили новое сообщение с ключевым словом `!help`.

Comment: Спасибо конечно за то что уделили время и придумали такой сложный вариант, но к моему сожалению я не знаю как реализовать и  подобное. Для меня пока что это очень сложно. Спасибо.

Comment: Не знаю как создать обработчик сообщений, как сделать массив в котором будет храниться hash строки. Как сделать счетчик это ещё вроде понятно (`Inc`). Не понял что имеется в виду под "не найденные записи удаляются, новые добавляются".

А вот под вторым маркером это второй вариант как я понял, звучит понятнее но и опять же я не знаю как генерировать hash строки и проверять количество шагов.

Comment: Если понятно что делать и не знаете как реализовать лучше создать новый вопрос. По поводу того что не понятно: Не найденные записи удаляются значит то что когда обновляется список сообщений и пришло новое сообщение, то старое одно исчезло (Вы же сами писали.) Так что нам нужно контролировать все, чтобы не держать "мусорные" записи .

Comment: Спасибо, я ещё два дня назад создал другой вопрос и решил проблему. дая

Comment: Прекрасно. Рад за Вас. Если текущий вопрос решен - можете установить галочку под ответом.